# String concatenation from within a single list

Tags: list, scala, concatenation

Scala is new to me so I'm not sure the best way to go about this.

I need to simply take the strings within a single list and join them.
So, `concat(List("a","b","c"))` returns `abc`.

Should I first see how many strings there are in the list, that way I can just loop through and join them all? I feel like that needs to be done first, that way you can use the lists just like an array and do `list[1]` append `list[2]` append `list[3]`, etc..

**Edit**:

Here's my idea, of course with compile errors..

```
def concat(l: List[String]): String = {
var len = l.length
var i = 0
    while (i < len) {
        val result = result :: l(i) + " "
    }
result
}
```

Comment: If you're going to join them anyway, why not just do the `concat`? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: That's the function I'm working on making..

Comment: What you're describing is a typical function. Unless you're trying to recreate `concat`, I'm not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: If you don't want an answer, this isn't really the place for your question. Not that it's not a good exercise, but SO is for answering.

Comment: You probably want to add that to the question, since you'll probably get the "concat already exists" kind of responses.

Comment: @syrion - It's possible to provide answers that are not literal answers, IMO. The OP is wanting answers that describe a process, not an end result.

Comment: @Jared - Fair enough. I have made my attempt. :)

Comment: @Jared where is this `concat(List[String])` method of which you speak?

Comment: @Luigi - I was thinking about [Array.concat](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.5/scala/Array$object.html#concat%28Seq[T]*%29).

Answer (score 37):

How about this, on REPL

```
List("a","b","c") mkString("")
```

or in script file

```
List("a","b","c").mkString("")
```

Answer (score 2):

Some options to explore for you:

1. imperative: for-loop; use methods from the List object to determine
   loop length  or use for-each List item
2. classical functional: recursive function, one element at the time using
3. higher-order functions: look at fold.

Given the basic level of the problem, I think you're looking at learning some fundamentals in programming. If the language of choice is Scala, probably the focus is on functional programming, so I'd put effort on solving #2, then solve #1. #3 for extra credits.

Comment: @John Redyns: Comment on your code: That qualifies for #1: Imperative approach. Following that approach, you probably want to declare `result` *outside* the while loop. Also, you are using the list `concat` method to do a string append, which will not work. You need to use a method of the String class, such as "+".  Would you give a try to the recursive form? Tip: List is a recursive data structure with head::tail.

Answer (score 1):

This exercise is designed to encourage you to think about the problem from a functional perspective. You have a set of data over which you wish to move, performing a set of identical operations. You've already identified the imperative, looping construct (`for`). Simple enough. Now, how would you build that into a functional construct, not relying on "stateful" looping?

Comment: My thought process:
1) Find how many strings the function has been submitted with
2) Then we have list[0] = a, list[1] = b, list[2] = c, etc.. and we know where it ends
3)Simply loop through all known strings we have accounted for and append them to a resulting list with all items, comma seperated.

Comment: As I said, that's the imperative construct.  There is a purely functional (one-line) implementation of a solution; there is also a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

> In functional programming, fold ... is a family of higher-order
>   functions that iterate an arbitrary function over a data structure in
>   some order and build up a return value.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29

That sounds like something you could use.

As string concatenation is associative (to be exact, it forms a monoid having the empty String as neutral element), the "direction" of the fold doesn't matter (at least if you're not bothered by performance).

Speaking of performance: In real life, it would be a good idea to use a `StringBuilder` for the intermediate steps, but it's up to you if you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

A bit longer that mkString but more efficient:

```
s.foldLeft(new StringBuilder())(_ append _).toString()
```

Comment: Note that the scala `mkString` method uses `StringBuilder` internally. I doubt that the proposed implementation is more efficient on large lists, for example because of anonymous function usage.

Answer (score -1):

I'm just assuming here that you are not only new to Scala, but also new to programming in general. I'm not saying SO is not made for newbies, but I'm sure there are many other places, which are better suited for your needs. For example books...

I'm also assuming that your problem doesn't have to be solved in a functional, imperative or some other way. It just has to be solved as a homework assignment.

So here are the list of things you should consider / ask yourself:

- If you want to concat **all** elements of the list do you really need to know how many there are?
- If you think you do, fine, but after having solved this problem using this approach try to fiddle around with your solution a little bit to find out if there is another way.
- Appending the elements to a resulting list is a thought in right direction, but think about this: in addition to being object-oriented Scala is also a full-blown functional language. You might not know what this means, but all you need to know for now is this: it is pretty darn good with things like lists (LISP is the most known functional language and it stands for LISt Processing, which has to be an indication of some kind, don't you think? ;)). So maybe there is some magical (maybe even Scala idiomatic) way to accomplish such a concatination without defining the resulting list yourself.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question :)